# Implementing Custom Int+Range List Solution

Tags: c#, list, range

I'm wondering if anyone can come up with a way to implement an array of numbers in a more memory efficient manner that will auto-organise itself into ranges. Example;

```
List testList = new List{1,2,3,4,5,6,7...};
```

vs

```
List<Range> testList = new List<Range>{1-3000,3002,4000-5000...};
```

Previously, I have asked a question just to confirm about whether or not this would in fact be a more memory efficient alternative. This question however pertains to actual application, how to implement this range list solution.

[Index Array Storage Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800536/index-array-storage-memory)

I imagine this would perhaps need to be a custom list solution that would be a mix of ints and ranges. I'm picturing being able to .Add([int]) to the list, at which point it would determine if the value would cause a range to be added or to simply add the int value to the list.

**Example**

```
RangeList rangeList = new RangeList{1, 4, 7-9};
rangeList.Add(2);
//rangeList -> 1-2, 4, 7-9
rangeList.Add(3);
//rangeList -> 1-3, 4, 7-9
```

**Details specific to my implementation**

In my particular case, I'm analysing a very large document, line by line. Lines that meet a certain criteria need to be identified and then the overall list of line indexes need to be presented to the user.

Obviously displaying "Lines 33-32019 identified" is preferable to "Lines 33,34,35...etc". For this case, numbers will always be positive.

Comment: Can your numbers be negative? Or is the sign bit "spare"?

Comment: I think this heavily depends in the usage of the class. If you add/remove new items very rarely, I'd implement it with focus on performance of fetching/calculating/whatever and when adding Items all the time with focus on the performance of adding/organizing.

Comment: I guess this question is a little too broad for SO. There are a lot of things to consider: how do you represent a `Range` (tuples, extra type)? A list normally contains elements of the same type, so you need to think about if you want to add single ints as `Range` of length 1...maybe you want an (implicit) cast operator from `int` to `Range`....and you need to implement an Enumerator for the list that enumerates the contained ranges...it's an interesting idea, but would mean to write a lot of code for you... so I still think it's too broad.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Good question, always positive. See my update.

Comment: @RenéVogt I see your point. However, I could put artificial constraints on the question to make it more specific but I don't think that would help. I have added in a description of my use-case, if that makes it more 'real world'.

Comment: One more point that René Vogt didn't mention is this: When adding a new int value, How do you know if you need to expand the previous range or start a new range?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Definitely, I believe this is where the main chunk of the effort/complexity comes in. Also, in some circumstances you may need to merge ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I would do is make a class which represents your range. You can provide some convenience like formatting as a string, and having an implicit cast from an int (This helps later implementation of the range list)

```
public class Range
{
    public int Start{get; private set;}
    public int End{get; private set;}

    public Range(int startEnd) : this(startEnd,startEnd)
    {           
    }

     public Range(int start, int end)
     {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
     }

    public static implicit operator Range(int i)
    {
        return new Range(i);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if(Start == End)
            return Start.ToString();
        return String.Format("{0}-{1}",Start,End);
    }
}
```

You can then begin a simple implementation of the `RangeList`. By providing an `Add` method you can use a list initializer similar to `List<T>`:

```
public class RangeList : IEnumerable<Range>
{
    private List<Range> ranges = new List<Range>();

    public void Add(Range range)
    {
        this.ranges.Add(range);
    }

    public IEnumerator<Range> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.ranges.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(){
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

At this point you can write some test code:

```
var rangeList = new RangeList(){
    new Range(1,10),
    15
};

foreach(var range in rangeList)
    Console.WriteLine(range);

// Outputs:
//  1-10
//  15
```

Live example at this point: http://rextester.com/NCZSA71850

The next thing to do is provide an overload of `Add` which takes an int and finds the right range or adds a new one. A naive implemntation might look like the below (Assuming the addition of an `Update` method on range)

```
public void Add(int i)
{
    // is it within or contiguous to an existing range
    foreach(var range in ranges)
    {
        if(i>=range.Start && i<=range.End)
            return; // already in a range
        if(i == range.Start-1)
        {
            range.Update(i,range.End);
            return;
        }
        if(i == range.End + 1)
        {
            range.Update(range.Start,i);
            return;
        }
    }
    // not in any ranges
    ranges.Add(i);
}
```

Live example at this point: http://rextester.com/CHX64125

However this suffers from a few deficiencies

1. Does not merge ranges (say you already have 1-10 and 12-20 and you `Add(11)`)
2. Does not re-order so if you have 1-5 and 20-25 and `Add(7)` this will be at the end not in the middle.

You can solve both problems by applying a sort after each addition, and some logic to determine if you should merge ranges

```
private void SortAndMerge()
{
    ranges.Sort((a,b) => a.Start - b.Start);
    var i = ranges.Count-1;
    do
    {
        var start = ranges[i].Start;
        var end = ranges[i-1].End;
        if(end == start-1)
        {
            // merge and remove
            ranges[i-1].Update(ranges[i-1].Start,ranges[i].End);
            ranges.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    } while(i-- >1);
}
```

This needs to be called after every change to the list.

```
public void Add(Range range)
{
    this.ranges.Add(range);
    SortAndMerge();
}

public void Add(int value)
{
    // is it within or contiguous to an existing range
    foreach(var range in ranges)
    {
        if(value>=range.Start && value<=range.End)
            return; // already in a range
        if(value == range.Start-1)
        {
            range.Update(value,range.End);
            SortAndMerge();
            return;
        }
        if(value == range.End + 1)
        {
            range.Update(range.Start,value);
            SortAndMerge();
            return;
        }
    }
    // not in any ranges
    ranges.Add(value);
    SortAndMerge();
}
```

Live example here: http://rextester.com/SYLARF47057

There are still some possible edge cases with this, which I urge you to work through.

**UPDATE**

The below will get this working as expected. This will merge up any added ranges/ints as you would expect and returns them correctly sorted. I've only changed the Add(Range) method, I think this is a fairly clean way of doing this.

```
public void Add(Range rangeToAdd)
{
    var mergableRange = new List<Range>();
    foreach (var range in ranges)
    {
        if (rangeToAdd.Start == range.Start && rangeToAdd.End == range.End)
            return; // already exists

        if (mergableRange.Any())
        {
            if (rangeToAdd.End >= range.Start - 1)
            {
                mergableRange.Add(range);
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (rangeToAdd.Start >= range.Start - 1
                && rangeToAdd.Start <= range.End + 1)
            {
                mergableRange.Add(range);
                continue;
            }

            if (range.Start >= rangeToAdd.Start
                && range.End <= rangeToAdd.End)
            {
                mergableRange.Add(range);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!mergableRange.Any()) //Standalone range
    {
        ranges.Add(rangeToAdd);
    }
    else //merge overlapping ranges
    {
        mergableRange.Add(rangeToAdd);
        var min = mergableRange.Min(x => x.Start);
        var max = mergableRange.Max(x => x.End);
        foreach (var range in mergableRange) ranges.Remove(range);
        ranges.Add(new Range(min, max));
    }

    SortAndMerge();
}
```

Finally, we need `if (ranges.Count > 1)` in the `SortAndMerge()` method to prevent an index error when the first range is added.

And with that, I think this fully satisfies my question.

Comment: This is a lot like what I had in mind, however please note you must also provide a way to update an existing range (so having the start and end as private setters is wrong) or replace it with a new range (note that this is specifically required in the question).

Comment: Don't forget to handle merging - say you already have 1..10 and 12..20 and you add 11

Comment: @windowskm Im trying to write you a better `Add` which ticks all the boxes... but the fire alarm has just gone off in my building :D Might be a delay!

Comment: Whoa, definitely not urgent so don't worry. Take care, hope all is ok.

Comment: @windowskm hah no problem. Still not evacuated. The fun of high rise offices. Anyway Ive updated my answer. Let me know if any problems/questions

Comment: So individual ints aren't removed if a subsequent range includes them. Example: rangeList.Add(3); rangeList.Add(new Range(1,5));

Comment: @windowskm are you asking me or telling me? See "edge cases" caveat :) Another one.... adding an overlapping range will not merge correctly unless they butt up (1-5) + (6-11) works but not (1-5) + (2-7)

Comment: No problem, I can correct it, just wasn't sure if you were aware! Figured it would be worthwhile having a complete solution here. I wouldn't be surprised if I'm not the only person to think of this question in future. :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh I was aware this wasnt a complete solution - hence my caveat. I think this answer is probably enough to get people going who would have the same question. You can also feel free to edit in any advances you make if you're so inclined. I'll make this community wiki

Comment: Updated the `Add(Range)` method and believe this is working as expected, caveats handled. :) Thanks again for your help!